# How can I stop x-axis labels in a dc.js bar chart re-rendering after being wrapped?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to wrap long labels in a dc.js bar chart. I've been able to find code to wrap the labels, but I'm having an issue with the labels being re-rendered on transitions.

See the gif below, the labels are wrapped correctly to start with, but when I make any changes, it seems to trigger a re-render (or redraw), which re-generates the labels to their initial state.

I've tried using each of the listeners in
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor
to try and wrap the labels before they get rendered, but it hasn't worked.

An example of the issue:
[image: Labels unwrapping]

## Function to wrap labels, one word per line

```py
    function wrap(text_orig, width, chart_id) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(text_orig._groups[0], function (x) {
            var text = select(x)
            var all_tspans = text.selectAll('tspan').size()
            console.log('all_tspans:', all_tspans)
            if(all_tspans > 1){
                return;
            }

            var    words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse()
            var    word
            var    lineNumber = 0
            var    lineHeight = 1.1 // ems
            var    y = text.attr("y")
            var    dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy"))
            var    tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em")

            while (word = words.pop()) {
                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
                ++lineNumber;
            }

        });
    }
```

## barChartTemplate is a composite chart defined elsewhere

```py
    barChartTemplate
    .dimension(dimension)
    .group(group)
    .x(scaleBand().domain(dimension)) 
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .on('renderlet', function(d){
        selectAll("#" + chartSettings.id + " g.x.axis .tick text")
        .call(wrap, 1, chartSettings.id);
    })
```

---

## With pretransition:

[image]

## Code

```py
barChartTemplate
    .dimension(dimension)
    .group(group)
    // .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value.n; })
    .x(scaleBand().domain(dimension)) 
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .on('pretransition', function(d){
        selectAll("#" + chartSettings.id + " g.x.axis .tick text")
            .call(wrap, 1, chartSettings.id);
    })
```

---

## Update:

As per Gordon's response below, .elasticX(true) seems to trigger a re-render, so removing this resolved the problem.

Comment: Glad you tried all the events. What result did you get with `pretransition`?

Comment: I've added in a gif with pretransition to the main question. It looks like they don't get wrapped, but actually stepping through the execution the wrapping code does run and the labels do get wrapped, but it seems as if they get re-rendered during the transition perhaps.

Comment: Does it work if you turn off transitions with `.transitionDuration(0)`? It is sometimes possible to modify dc.js attributes that have transitions on them (or d3-axis attributes in this case), but it's pretty difficult.

Comment: Ok, applying .transitionDuration(0) does make it stop flickering to the 'unwrapped' state, so it seems to be happening during the transition but, this leaves the chart with no transitions. Is it possible to apply this 'wrap' function as a default behaviour when the labels are being rendered? Or are there other ways, like stopping transitions on just the labels?

Comment: Good questions! I don't have time to investigate right now, but if you find anything please report back. If it helps your search, this is all d3-axis stuff; dc.js is just applying the axis function in a transition.

Comment: FWIW it seems like the immediate cause is `elasticX(true)`, as you can see [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/L0w9drpx/53/). I'm not sure why, but I guess changing the domain of the ordinal scale causes d3-axis to rerender the tick labels (even if they are the same values?)

Comment: Oh brilliant, I removed elasticX(true) and it's working perfectly! Thanks.